Как открыть окно поиска google в окне приложения в Avalonia UI?
у меня есть TextBox и по нажатию кнопки я хочу сделать так, чтобы открывалось окно с результатами поиска по запросу который я ввел в textbox. как это сделать?

Варианта 2: 1. Через HttpClient отправлять нужный запрос на нужный сайт и парсить ответ в нужные объекты, после чего выводить результат в нужном виде. 2. Использовать полноценный браузер, встраивать его в приложение и открывать там просто нужную ссылку, но как по мне это самый ужасный и самый бесячий вариант в современных реалиях)

Ну а как например работает FireFox? Там же сначала обычное текстовое поле, а потом после нажатия Enter то выходит система google

Ну это полноценный Web движок, который умеет разбирать HTML, рендерить это все и выводить на экран. Если вам надо такое, то выбирайте 2-й вариант, ищите компонент веб браузера (например Webview2), устанавливайте, внедряйте в окно, открывайте через него что надо. Но повторю, это самое ужасное решение, самое бесячее решение из-за чего многие будут страдать) И раз у вас Авалония, то подумайте дополнительно о кросплатформенности, ибо браузеры очень завязаны на OS.

А если выбрать первый вариант? Тогда будет легче это реализовать?

Зависит от задачи, от сайта, от того, что вы хотите) Условный поисковик - ну, как по мне, очень странно видеть в приложении вдруг огромное окно, в котором будет гугл, зачем мне тогда это приложение, если я могу сам взять и открыть гугл, найдя там нужную информацию. А вот если это будет в виде простого и удобного списка, с нужным мне функционалом, то это уже имеет смысл. Но опять, я не знаю что вы там делаете, я просто говорю какие у вас есть возможности - писать запросы самостоятельно, или автоматизировать браузер.

Чтоб вы понимали почему 2-й вариант плох - если пользуетесь Steam или например Spotify, может Discord, ну или рядом других популярных приложений, посмотрите сколько они занимают сидя в фоне, у меня например они фоном кушают от 100 до 500мб RAM и вечно что-то высчитывают., как думаете, почему это так? Все просто, их UI - это браузер, тот-же Chrome, но только заточенный под один конкретный сайт. В итоге получаем, что приложение, которое от силы может 50мб RAM кушать, вдруг кушает 500 и все из-за лени разработчиков... Так что, думайте сами, чего вам надо)

Я делаю просто для практики и хочу попробовать сделать, что-то вроде своего браузера. Чисто для практики, а вот потом уже делать из этого, что-то что могло бы быть полезным и может хоть чуть-чуть нужным. Но я не понял как это сделать через  первый способ и реализовать это в Avalonia?

Свой браузер вы не сделаете ни за что в жизни. Сейчас во всем мире существует только 2 браузера - Chrome и FireFox, все остальное, это их обертки. Поэтому тут стоит выражаться более конкретно, ибо если вы хотите сделать свой браузер - тогда идите и изучайте что такое HTML, CSS, JS, DOM, как рендерить это все, как обрабатывать, и так далее. Пишите свое ядро, которое будет все это делать. Если у вас цель сделать очередную "обертку", то я вам первым сообщением сказал как - ищите компонент браузера (например WebView2 (хром)) и внедряйте его проект. Вроде понятно все сразу написал, или нет?

Вон я пошел в гугл и написал "Авалония WebView2", нашел эту официальную новость в которой говорится, что в авалонию встроили DotNetBrowser, который в свою очередь является цитата: Chromium-based WebView. Ну и смотрите, у вас уже из коробки есть WebView, вроде нормальны и вроде кросплатформенный... И вы уже больше 6 часов что-то пытаетесь тут разузнать, вместо того, чтоб пойти и поискать нужную вам информацию самостоятельно. И да, первый способ - это про ручной парсинг, не про браузер (отображение) который вы хотите.

Я посмотрел и увидел, что DotNetBrowser платный, но я нашел примеры с WebView2 на гитхабе, можно ли тогда обойтись без DotNetBrowser

Пробуйте, изучайте. Но помните про крослатформенность.

Я понял, спасибо вам за подсказки
